# Remove part of the file using Buffered Stream

Tags: c#

Is there any possible way to remove a part of a file using the `BufferedStream` in a way that I do not have to read the whole file and move data from one position to another?

I'm indexing the data inside of a file using a `KeyValuePair<int, String>` object so I know that what record can be found at what position and with what length. Then I can `Seek` in the file and move to the position I don't need, but by using the `WriteByte` or `Write` method I can only convert that block to white space or NULL character which isn't very smart.

Is it possible at all and if so what is the proper approach?

Comment: No, you can't. A file's data resides contiguously in a sector on a disk, say `abcdefg`. Now if you want to remove `cde`, you can't have `ab???fg` remaining, where `???` occupies zero space. You'll have to re-write the part after the part you want to remove, starting from the position of the bytes you removed, in other words: write `fg` after `abc`, and mark `c` as the new end of the file.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I know that a work around would be to flag the data as deleted temporarily and then clean it when the load is rather low. But assuming that the file contains 80,000,000 (exactly my Big Data case), an overwrite would be so expensive, especially when you have to do it for several times in a short interval. Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: See duplicate. You cannot circumvent having to rewrite (parts of) the file if you want to remove bytes from the middle. If you have accepted and implemented that but it doesn't perform, then [edit] your question.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Ok, do you know if databases (like SQL Server) do the same when a record is updated or deleted (overwriting data), or the just add flags like my assumption?

Comment: @CodeCaster: Regarding the duplicate post, I read but the things is that I'm trying not do it like that (accepted answer) as I explained.

Comment: I don't know the SQL Server implementation by heart. As far as I know, yes, database systems can use a flag on each row that indicates whether that row was deleted, or offload that to a structure next to the table data.

Comment: Yes, the duplicate _does_ answer your question. You want to remove bytes from the middle of a file, and how you do that is irrelevant: it is a principle that spans over programming languages and APIs.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I read that post again, and I noticed someone mentioned Sparse Files, that seems interesting, if you don't mind CodeCaster, what is your idea about that?

Comment: You seem to have records. Find a way to mark them as deleted (and add them to a free list). You then have a new set of problems: allocation and fragmentation.

Comment: Sparse files are files where contiguous zeroes take up less space than in a regular file, and is not the direction you should be looking in. One solution would be to use what @Henk said, but again, your question as-is (_"how to remove bytes from the middle of a file"_) is answered in the duplicate.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I can already flag the records, but what would be the use of the `Free List`? what do I have to track them for? I can skip the flagged location when reading the file back and upon deletion I can delete the record from memory as well.